# Parse: Promise.when with many promises?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Parse documentation ( https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when ) explains that when using Parse.Promise.when, it is kosher to specify an array of promises:

```
var p1 = Parse.Promise.as(1);
var p2 = Parse.Promise.as(2);
var p3 = Parse.Promise.as(3);

var promises = [p1, p2, p3];
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
  console.log(r1);  // prints 1
  console.log(r2);  // prints 2
  console.log(r3);  // prints 3
});
```

...which is sweet!

But, do you really have to list every single promise response in your then() function? Not really feasible if you have an array of promises of unknown size, and not very DRY!

Can I do this?

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(responses) {
  console.log(responses[0]);  // prints 1
  console.log(responses[1]);  // prints 2
  console.log(responses[2]);  // prints 3
});
```

?

Comment: I'd use native promises and use `Promise.all` which has semantics which are a lot better.

Comment: How are you sure that Parse.Promises are compatible with native promises?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make use of JavaScript's builtin special variable, [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) like this

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
  console.log(arguments[0]);  // prints 1
  console.log(arguments[1]);  // prints 2
  console.log(arguments[2]);  // prints 3
});
```

Comment: Apparently the Parse JS SDK v1.7.x `Parse.Promise.when` will return an array of results, as expected, and as documented. See here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/158